# Uploading a file via the Google Drive API to a service account and sharing with a group - no notification

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a very simple Python script that uploads a file to a service account, then shares it with a group.  This script worked fine up until May of this year, when it suddenly stopped sending email notifications to the group of the shared file (it still updates the file, and the permissions are correct, so it is only the email notification that fails.)  I thought perhaps some setting on the group might have changed defaults, but I could find nothing relevant.

Searching here, I did find the sendNotificationEmails parameter, which is meant to default to true.  I tried forcing it to true anyways, with no results.

For reference, after the relevant oauth stuff, the code looks like:

```
file = drive_service.files().update(fileId=id, body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()

fileId = file['id']

body = {
'role': 'writer',
'type': 'group',
'value': 'groupname'
}

perm = drive_service.permissions().insert( fileId=fileId, sendNotificationEmails=True, body=body ).execute()
```

Can anyone explain why the group no longer receives email notifications, and how I might re-enable them?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's support admitted that this was a bug.

As of Friday April 3 2015, it appears to have been fixed.

Comment: This seems to be happening again. I tried w/ both v2 and v3 neither of them sends email notification to the group.